# XCode 8.2.1 Autolayout: Issues with busy, populated UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

I have a project in XCode 8.2.1, Swift 3 that I has a lot of UILabels, UIButtons and UITextFields showing a lot of data (forms essentially). The app is iPad-only, landscape-only and targets 9.0 and above.

I've tried manually assigning constraints (which takes a ton of time) and I've tried letting the IDE "Add Missing Constraints" and "Reset to Suggested Constraints" in the Storyboards. If I remove all constraints from the VC, it gets the "form" almost right, but a few things are still out of place.

I am doing nothing in viewDidLoad() or any other positioning related coding.

Here is a screenshot of my Storyboard:
[image]

And here is the same UIViewController in the iPad Air 2 (iOS version 10.2) Simulator with suggested constraints:
[image: Storyboard rendered using reset/suggested constraints]

a) How should one go about using autolayout with a ton of controls needed, where spacing and alignment is essential?
b) Why is XCode resizing buttons and controls that I specifically assign sizes to? I have to keep resizing things now and then when the Storyboard's reopened.

Appreciate any suggestions. Mind-numbing and I'm wasting way more time with layout than functionality opposed to 7.3 and older.

Comment: You have to bite the bullet im afraid, maybe break sections up into their own subviews so that logical sections can be autolayout'ed against other sections, instead of keeping track of each UI element against the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how I've broken down a rather complex screen in an iPad app.

[image]

The main view consists of two container views.  The container on the left embeds a UIableViewContoller, the one on the right embeds a UIViewController.  The UIViewController itself then embeds another UITableViewController.  Each controller communicates necessary changes back up the container chain through delegates.

This allows me to control the layout within each container section much better as you have less constraints to deal with for any given controller.

Secondly, possibly you have some mega controller class that controls all the logic for all those views you have crammed in there.  When you break them into their own controllers you can break the mega class into separate classes that control just their section of the UI, making more readable and encapsulated code.

Comment: Definitely adds complexity due to chaining, but certainly makes sense. Should have noted I have a couple of container UIViews in my layout, but this is a step further.I'll give this route a try and report back. Thanks, man.

Comment: Ultimately, I think this is probably the most "will work for the time you have to put into it" solution. Thanks for the suggestion. For now, I'm going with no Autolayout, as it's an Enterprise App, so I have a narrow target list to support. Spent half a day grouping things into subviews in the controller and that helped, but still left it unmanageable, not to mention the trouble of adding anything new. Autolayout works great for some views, but it's hell for others.

Comment: Hopefully at least the idea will help you in the long run as you refactor the app bit by bit.  The only other thing that might help would be to use stack views, but with all the views you have, nesting so many stack views might be just as much of a headache.  Good luck!